# jQuery slideToggle(); bootstrap 3 not smooth animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to animate my menu bar however it just drops down without the animation playing I have checked to make sure I have jQuery installed and its there. Any ideas why its just drops instead of animating as it should?

```js
var tab = $('#menu .menu')

tab.on('click', function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();

    });
```

```css
.menu-bar {
top: 20px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: table;}
.logo {

    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;


}
.menu {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 10px 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.menu ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.menu a {
    color: #333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.menu a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 1;
}
/*deviders*/
.home{
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #423840;
}

.about {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #8dd8f8;
}

.service {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #9D714F;
}

.info{
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #eee;
}

.contact {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<head>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <a class="menu-bar" data-toggle="collapse" href="#menu">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Bu0B6O8.png" alt="Logo" class = "logo">
            </a>
         <div class="collapse menu" id="menu">

                <ul class="list-inline">

                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#service">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#info">Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
         </div>



<section id="home" class="home">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <h1>Home</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="about" class="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Profolio</h1>
                <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="service" class="service">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Service</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Contact Section -->
<section id="info" class="info">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Info</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<section id="contact" class="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Contact us</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Check this simple fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zu3o3hfq/)

You have to toggle menu like this way, (include **Jquery** first)

Here is the simple basic of **toggle uses for Menu**,

**Jquery**

```
$( ".menu-bttn" ).click(function() {
    $( ".main-nav" ).slideToggle(300);
});
```

**Sample HTML Menu**

```
<a class="menu-bttn">Menu</a>
<ul class="main-nav">
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Sample CSS**

```
.menu-bttn{
   display:inline-block;
   background:#111111;
   color:#FFFFFF;
   padding:10px 18px;
   cursor:pointer;
}

.main-nav {
   display:none;
   list-style: none;
   margin:0;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

.main-nav a{
   display:block;
   background:#666666;
   color:#FFFFFF;
   padding:10px 18px;
   text-decoration: none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your JQuery at the end of your body ?

```
<body>
... your code ...

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: What kind of animation your menu bar needs ? (sry for my english :) )

Comment: Smooth slide toggle.

Comment: I try to find something to help you :)